# Which Magento Module is that? (Custom Option: Children, Image, Description)

Tags: magento

a freelancer have install this Plugin. I must have this for a other project.

What is the name of this plugin and how i can find it?:

Screenshot:
http://s1.directupload.net/images/140722/tv684ifm.png

Can add Children, Image and Description to Custom Option.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: what is the url? i mean index action name and etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!
[Advanced Product Options](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-product-options.html)